# How do I show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I have the following Problem:

> Let $G$ be a group and $H<G$ be a subgroup. We assume that $G\setminus H=H/G$, i.e. every left-$H$ coset is also a right-$H$ coset and vice versa. We have just shown that $1\in H(g'g^{-1})$ now we need to deduce from this fact that H is normal. We also know that for every $g\in G$ there exists $g'\in G$ such that $gH=Hg'$.

I somehow don't see it. Because we only know that $1=hg'g^{-1}\Leftrightarrow g=hg'$. So if $h=1$ then it would follow immediately, but I don't think that this is true. So could someone give me a **hint** (you don't need to solve the whole thing).
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use $g = hg'$ to prove that $gH = Hg$.

Comment: So does it work like this? $(2)\Rightarrow g=hg'$ Therefore its enough to show that $hg'H=Hhg' \Leftrightarrow hg'H=Hg' \Leftrightarrow g'H=Hg'$ But since we know that for all $g\in G$ there exists $g'\in G$ s.t. $gH=Hg'$ we get that $hg'H=Hg'\Leftrightarrow g'H=Hg'$ and we are done.

Comment: I think your proof is a bit confusing, I do not really follow. You mean it is enough to show that $g'H = Hg'$? Anyway here: If $g = hg'$, then $Hg = Hhg' = Hg' = gH$.

Comment: yes I meant the same but wrote it really confusing! thanks